# Using webgl2 with PIXI

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

I am trying to initialize PIXI to use the webgl2 context but I cannot find much documentation on the subject. From what I have been able to find, I have created:

```
import * as PIXI from 'pixi.js';

export default class App {
    constructor() {
        this.renderer = new PIXI.Renderer({ context: 'webgl2' });
    }
}
```

But this throws an error of:

`gl.getContextAttributes is not a function`

I also tried using `{ context: 'experimental-webgl' }` with the same result.

Comment: It uses WebGL 2 by default.

Answer (score 1):

Which version of Pixi are you using? Pixi 5 uses webgl by default, and you must import from pixi.js-legacy to get a canvas-backed Renderer.

> Since WebGL and WebGL2 are now first-class, we have removed the
>   canvas-based fallback from the default pixi.js package. If you need
>   CanvasRenderer, you should switch to use pixi.js-legacy instead.

Source: [Pixi 5 Migration guide](https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js/wiki/v5-Migration-Guide#-publishing-changes)

Also, the `context` parameter to [PIXI.Renderer()](http://pixijs.download/release/docs/PIXI.Renderer.html#Renderer) is not a string, it is an object. I believe you only use this when you want to re-use an existing context.